# Querying localized data in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localization, aggregation-framework

Having data 'localized' like this:

```
{
  "cs": [
    {
      "cID": "00001",
      "title": {
        "en": "title en1",
        "de": "title de1"
      },
      "desc": {
        "en": "desc en1",
        "de": "desc de1"
      },
      "startDate": 20210801,
      "endDate": 20210809,
      "numDays": 8
    },
    {
      "cID": "00002",
      "title": {
        "en": "title en2",
        "de": "title de2"
      },
      "desc": {
        "en": "desc en2",
        "de": "desc de2"
      },
      "startDate": 20210701,
      "endDate": 20210715,
      "numDays": 14
    }
  ]
}
```

What would be the best way to query this taking user locale (passed to query as param) into account? For example, if "en" was passed, the query should return this for "cID": "00001" :

```
    {
      "cID": "00001",
      "title": "title en1",
      "desc": "desc en1",
      "startDate": 20210801,
      "endDate": 20210809,
      "numDays": 8
    }
```

Ideally, the query should be 'generic' and not filter specifically the 'title' and 'desc' objects.

I know that:

```
db.cs.find({
  "cID": "00001"
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "cID": 1,
  "title": "$title.en",
  "desc": "$desc.en",
  "startDate": 1,
  "endDate": 1,
  "numDays": 1
})
```

will give me:

```
[
  {
    "cID": "00001",
    "desc": "desc en1",
    "endDate": 2.0210809e+07,
    "numDays": 8,
    "startDate": 2.0210801e+07,
    "title": "title en1"
  }
]
```

but it would be tricky to handle it with many locales and different data models in different queries.

Mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/9erh-VYiOO4

Comment: Are you using `mongoose` os something similar? Which language are you using? Or is only a `mongo` query?

Comment: It's a node.js / express app. I am not using mongoose. I am using MongoDB Node.JS Driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `title` array, `$cond` to match `local` and return match result to value, same process for description array

```
 {
    $addFields: {
      title: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$title",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.locale", "pl"] }, "$$this.value", "$$value"]
          }
        }
      },
      description: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$description",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.locale", "pl"] }, "$$this.value", "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

for the generic option you can make a function with two parameters first one is input field with `$` sign and second one is locale:

```
function languageFilter(inputField, locale) {
  return {
    $reduce: {
      input: inputField,
      initialValue: "",
      in: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.locale", locale] }, "$$this.value", "$$value"]
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Your final query would be:

```
let locale = "pl";
db.cs.aggregate([
  { $match: { cID: "00001" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      title: languageFilter("$title", locale)
      description: languageFilter("$description", locale)
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a generic query one would need the aggregation framework as it has some handy operators to help you with this. To start with, you would need to convert the embedded document into array of key/value pairs and then filter the array on the key field passing in the locale as the parameter.

For example, convert the document

```
  "title": {
    "en": "title en2",
    "de": "title de2"
  },
```

to an array

```
  "title": [
    { "k": "en", '"v": "title en2" },
    { "k": "de", "v": "title de2" }
  ],
```

using [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator. You can then filter this array on the key field using the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator as

```
{
    '$filter': {
        'input': { '$objectToArray': '$title' },
        'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this.k', locale] }
    }
}
```

where the variable locale is derived from the passed parameter.

Once you have the filtered array, getting the value field requires the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator applied on the value key as

```
{ 
    '$arrayElemAt': ['$title.v', 0]
}
```

So in the end you will have to run a pipeline like this:

```
var locale = 'en';

db.cs.aggregate([
    { '$match': { "cID" : "00001" } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'title': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$title' },
                'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this.k', locale] }
            }
        },
        'desc': {
            '$filter': {
                'input': { '$objectToArray': '$desc' },
                'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this.k', locale] }
            }
        }
    } },

    { '$addFields': {
        'title': { 
            '$arrayElemAt': ['$title.v', 0]
        },
        'desc': { 
            '$arrayElemAt': ['$desc.v', 0]
        }
    } }
]);
```

And with some refactoring:

```
var locale = 'en';
var getFilterOperatorExpression = function (field) {
    return {
        '$filter': {
            'input': { '$objectToArray': '$'+ field },
            'cond': { '$eq': ['$$this.k', locale] }
        }
    }
};
var getValueOperatorExpression = function (field) { 
    return { 
        '$arrayElemAt': ['$'+ field +'.v', 0]
    }
};

db.cs.aggregate([
    { '$match': { "cID" : "00001" } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'title': getFilterOperatorExpression('title'),
        'desc': getFilterOperatorExpression('desc'),
    } },

    { '$addFields': {
        'title': getValueOperatorExpression('title'),
        'desc': getValueOperatorExpression('desc')
    } }
]);
```

Comment: $objectToArray is not needed if we specify 'title' as array []. Other than this, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Przemek In your original question there is no mention of specifying `title` as an array hence this solution of using `$objectToArray` directly addresses the problem of `title` being an embedded document. It won't be a good idea to change my answer as it will mislead people who come along and see that answers provided do not match what you have asked.

Comment: Could you please take a look at https://mongoplayground.net/p/hvbMNKAuPw4 and help me figure out how to do the same thing within the roomDetails object? I'm getting lost in these mongo pipelines

Comment: In your solution you suggest to change “title” to be an array. I did this. When I do this using objectToArray function returns an error as it already gets the array. Removing this function makes the solution work. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please create a new question for the `roomDetails` query? That way you can get enough help not just from me but from the wider SO community at large.

Comment: Posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943723/mongodb-aggregate-pipelines-with-linked-object